# Django REST API Regex on filter set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get regex to work with my Django views using the rest API.  The API seems to be working fine but I am not able to get it to perform searches using regex. I have the back end filters included in my settings.

```
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_datatables.filters.DatatablesFilterBackend',
        'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.OrderingFilter',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
    ),
```

Example views.

```
    queryset = Server.objects.all().order_by('hostname')
    serializer_class = ServerSerializer
    filterset_fields = (
        'hostname',
        'region',
        'system_model',
    )
    search_fields = (
        'hostname',
    )
```

I have tried adding $ to the hostname in filterset however I get an error that no field matches.  It does seem to be reading the $ as regex. Not sure if that only works in SEARCH fields. Still a bit confused between filter fields and search fields. Essentially I am trying to get it to allow me to perform a search like /api/servers/?hostname=.*name.*&system_model=.*hp.*  Basically allow regex searching against the filter fields if that makes sense.

Comment: No regex for filter fields. With filters, you usually want an exact match. You may create a filter class and define the filters yourself how you need them to work

Comment: Hmm not good news.  I guess I could write custom function to capture the URL and perform queries against the DB returning a JSON.  However there is the multiple tables in SQL to deal with.  Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Have you actually checked the django-filter docs? You could just create a custom FilterClass or Backend from the main one and use regex filtering which is already supported in Django ORM. Shouldn't be that difficult